# Nissan Almera 2006 Engine Oil Overfilled

Tags: engine, oil, oil-change

Was doing an oil change 2 days ago, have done it numerous times before, for whatever reason, I've overfilled it this time.

If I was to put a measurement on it, it's over by about 2-4mm on the max line, not more than 5mm (judging by eye).

Weather has been freezing outside so I don't really fancy ramping it up and redoing/draining.

Due to the cars age and mileage it does burn oil so will drop eventually.

Is the overfill something to be concerned about?